# jQuery Mobile + MVC 3 + Request.Path

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to use jQuery Mobile + MVC 3 to run a new mobile site. One of the requirements is that Google Analytics be installed and tracking page views properly. I inserted GA code as I normally would, but it appears to be tracking only the home page and none of the other site pages. After some review, it appears I need to split up the GA javascript code into two separate blocks. So, in the  element, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xx-xxxxxx-x']);
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
  </script>
```

Then, just before the closing  tag I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        try {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '@Model.RequestPath']);
        } catch (err) { }
    });
</script>
```

**The problem:** @Model.RequestPath ALWAYS returns "/". I've stepped through the debugger and seen that the property is populated with the appropriate path (i.e. /somedirectory/somepage"), but when it hits the view, it just gets a "/".

**Important Info:**

- Model.RequestPath is configured to return the current value of Request.Url.AbsolutePath.
- Changing the action method of an interior page to set the RequestPath property to something constant has no effect. It's like it's using the view model to populate the page (the page renders as expected) but the RequestPath property seems to be getting modified at some point. I'm confused as to how the debugger shows that it's populated with the correct path, but then outputs "/" when it gets to the view.
- I have two pages: index.cshtml which is the home page and is the first page served. The rest of the interior pages use SiteMaster.cshtml. They both have identical GA code.
- When I load the page, the debugger hits the controller action for my request (as I'd expect) and the model is populated with the correct path (however the view still outputs a "/").
- When I do a "View Source" in FireFox the debugger fires again except this time it's hitting the controller action for my home page.
- I changed the GA code on SiteMaster.cshtml to call "trackPageview1" and on index.cshtml to call "trackPageview2" just so I can see when doing a view source which one is being called. It's ALWAYS trackPageview2, which means that its always pulling from index.html, even when I'm on a page that uses the SiteMaster.cshtml layout file. This would help to explain why the RequestPath is always "/" but I still don't understand why it's not outputting the markup from the master layout file instead.

I'm positive this has something to do with jQuery Mobile and the way it facilitates page requests via AJAX but I'm stuck trying to figure this out. Thought I'd post and see if anyone here can help while I continue to research on my own.

I'll clarify this post with more details if necessary as answers come in or as I find more information.

Comment: Try doing `@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` instead of `@Model.RequestPath` just to see if the URL that gets rendered to the page is any different.

Comment: I just edited my post because I realized I forgot to mention that Model.RequestPath is configured to return Request.Url.AbsolutePath. I've tried replacing Model.RequestPath with Request.Url.AbsolutePath in the view and experienced the same behavior.

Comment: See my answer. I'm thinking you are getting script conflicts. You should only have to drop the GA code on the layout page.

Comment: Also, try `@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` instead of `@Request.Url.AbsolutePath`.

Comment: AbsoluteUri simply outputs the protocol and domain name instead of the relative path. So instead of "/" on all pages, I get "http://www.site.com/" on all pages.

Comment: Okay now that's weird. You should be getting the full request Url with AbsoluteUri

Comment: Well that's the problem. The request url ALWAYS seems to be the home page, no matter what page of the site I'm on. Again, I think this has to do with how jQuery handles page requests.

Comment: This is a very useful question. +1 from me and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I use.  (Very similiar to Nicholas)

If it finds a hash(#) in windows.location, it parses out the path after the hash.
Example: http://www.mysite.com/about/#/contact ,  url='/contact'

If the hash is not present, like when a page is first loaded, it uses windows.location.pathname instead
Example: http://www.mysite.com/about , url='/about'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    var url = window.location.toString();
    var hashLocation = url.indexOf("#");
    if (hashLocation != -1) {
        url = url.substring(hashLocation + 1);
    }
    else {
        url = window.location.pathname.toString();
    }

    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-XX");    
        pageTracker._trackPageview(url);
    } catch (err) { }
});           
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just drop Google Analytics code in the master without any modifications. Is there a reason you are putting the code on pages that inherit from the master? GA will track the different pages that load, all you have to do is drop the code on the layout page.

Comment: That's what we did initially. It didn't work. It only tracks the home page. The fix for this that I'm attempting is based off of this post: http://blog.ertesvag.no/post/3586027043/using-google-analytics-with-jquery-mobile. Google Analytics works slightly differently with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I've never heard of this issue before. I don't recall jQuery Mobile ever messing with my GA code :/

Answer (score 0):

How about using location.href in conjunction with the code from this Using *Google Analytics with jQuery Mobile* [blog](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2011/01/10/google-analytics-and-jquery-mobile/) entry:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        try {
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("YOUR_GA_ID");
            pageTracker._trackPageview(location.href.replace('#', ''));
        } catch(err) {

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That looks nice. You might consider removing the # from the whole href and send it to the tracker, because it is the requested page name then.

Comment: @naugtur - change to location.href.replace('#', '')